# Wrong order of commands, the calendar always shows the penultimate date (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, user-interface, calendar

I made a little powershell script (with GUI), where you can display your computer startup / shutdown time on a specific date. My problem is, that everytime you choose the desired date on the calendar, it displays the startup / shutdown time from the date I chose before. So when I start the program and choose 16/1/2021 it displays the date I picked, the last time I opened the program e.g 8/1/2021. What is wrong with the order of the commands. Thanks for the help! Im new to PowerShell btw. :)

Code:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework
$GUI1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Calendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button


$Calendar.Location = '105,23'
$Calendar.Size = '250,250'
$Calendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$Calendar.ShowTodayCircle = $false


$Button.Location = '125,315'
$Button.Size = '225,100'
$Button.Text = "Select this date"
$Button.Add_Click({

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("PC Started at: $event1`nPC Shutdown at: $event2")

})



$GUI1.Size = '500,500'
$GUI1.Controls.Add($Calendar)
$GUI1.Controls.Add($Button)
$GUI1.ShowDialog() | Out-Null


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


$date = $calendar.SelectionStart
$end = $date.AddMinutes(1439)

$date


$event1 = Get-EventLog -LogName System -After $date -Before $end | Where { 6005-contains $_.EventID} | Select -ExpandProperty TimeGenerated -First 1
$event2 = Get-EventLog -LogName System -After $date -Before $end | Where { 6006-contains $_.EventID} | Select -ExpandProperty TimeGenerated -First 1
```

Comment: move 5 line from end to inside add_click section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**like this**

```
$Button.Add_Click({
$date = $calendar.SelectionStart
$end = $date.AddMinutes(1439)
$date
    $event1 = Get-EventLog -LogName System -After $date -Before $end | Where { 6005-contains $_.EventID} | Select -ExpandProperty TimeGenerated -First 1
    $event2 = Get-EventLog -LogName System -After $date -Before $end | Where { 6006-contains $_.EventID} | Select -ExpandProperty TimeGenerated -First 1
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("PC Started at: $event1`nPC Shutdown at: $event2")

 })
```